# CMS package as web development framework

Tags: php, frameworks, content-management-system, web

We've been using for long time web development frameworks based on PHP libraries (CakePHP, Symphony, Zend). Besides the MVC aspects of our applications we must implement now a parallel content provisioning system with the most advanced possible editing functionality, as a CMS provides. Our constraints would be that the "web-framework-CMS" to be opensource and to exclusively generate HTML-CSS-JS-PHP code (no intermediate code) that can be directly interpreted by a browser when the application is executed. Some of the CMSs we've looked at are using their proprietary set of instructions which are HTML translated by the CMS engine at run time. In other words, except for the provisioning or object creation phase we'd like that the CMS don't intervene. I kindly appreciate your expert opinion about such an existing solution.
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for a list of CMS written in PHP? Drupal, Wordpress, Jooma, Expression Engine.. etc. I don't understand your other requirements or if that includes or excludes any from the list I just gave.

Comment: @Mike B: Sorry for my lengthy question. Of course I know all the packages you mention, they are really CMSs written in PHP but not really flexible web development frameworks and I'm not looking for a list, but for a recommendation; I already have experience with WP and eZ Publish. My point has been perfectly summarized by Andrew Sledge below and Drupal is a package that is close to these requirements. Wouldn't be any others close to a "CMS for non-content usage", more recently started, even if not so 'well established'?

Comment: Would it be fair to say that you're looking for an extensible cms? Andrew's answer doesn't really make a point so much as it gives an example. Maybe it would help me if you explain why Drupal is a good example but Wordpress isn't.

Comment: @MikeB: Right. Basically we want to take advantage of the PHP dev environment so that we can extend the functionality, while the basic CMS engine to serve for content provisioning of the application that we'll develop. It is the Drupal case, that uses pure PHP language, allowing to tweak objects and templates, unlike eZ Publish, for instance, that has a proprietary intermediate language for templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal, written in PHP, is often used as a framework for non-content uses.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms our findings so far (just looked at the Bakeoff PHP web frameworks competition in Boston). I wonder if there are newer opensource initiatives because this is a new hot spot.